# When to use 仕上げ and when to use 仕上がり?

Tags: nouns, synonyms

From my dictionary, both of them are nouns and mean finish:

- 仕上げ - Finish, finishing, finishing touches
- 仕上がり- Finish, end, completion, result

What is the difference between them?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/84177/7810

Answer (score 7, accepted):

仕上げ is  a noun corresponding to **transitive** *to finish* and 仕上がり to **intransitive** *to finish*.

- 仕上げ means *someone's action of finishing/having finished something*
- 仕上がり means *something's finished state*

---

Examples:

- 仕上げの締め切りは明日だ *The deadline of finishing is tomorrow*

Here 仕上がり cannot be used.

- 仕上げが素晴らしい  *They have finished it beautifully*
- 仕上がりが素晴らしい *The finish is beautiful*

The former sounds praising the finisher's job while the latter sounds praising the end result of the finished object.

- 仕上げが遅くなった
- 仕上がりが遅くなった

Here both mean more or less the same *Finishing it took long(er than it supposed to)*. Literally the former is *It took me long to finish it* and the latter *It took long for the object to be finished*.